# swal delete and cancel button both deletes the data

Tags: ajax

I'm working in php laravel.
what i want is on deleting a record from data-table(loaded using ajax), if the user wants to delete a record they can click the delete button.
Upon clicking the delete button the sweetalert(swal) is used with DELETE and CANCEL button as shown below:

```
function deleteFeeds(id) {
    swal({
        title: "Are You Sure?",
        text: "",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
        confirmButtonText: "yes",
        closeOnConfirm: true,
    }).then(function (isConfirm) {
        if(isConfirm)
            {
                $.ajax({
                    headers: {  
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    },

                    url: baseUrl + 'deleteFeed/' + id,
                    method: "POST",
                    success: function (data) {
                        swal({
                            title: "deleted",
                            text: "deleted_successfully",
                            type: "success",
                            confirmButtonColor: "#00cc00",
                            confirmButtonText: "Confirm",
                        });
                        window.location.reload();

                    }
                });

            }
            else{
                swal("Cancelled", "Your feed is safe :)", "error");

            }


    });
}
```

But if the user selects the CANCEL button the data gets deleted which should not happen.

can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

use `isConfirm.value` instead of  `isConfirm` for if condition